# How to get the active tmux window's name?

Tags: vim, tmux

I want to write a script that gets the active tmux window's name and uses it as a variable for my vim session. Is this possible? I looked through the tmux manual and didn't see anything.

Answer (score 34):

You can use `display-message -p` to query the name of the active window (among other things):

```
tmux display-message -p '#W'
```

If you want to target a specific window, you can use `-t`:

```
tmux -t «target-window» display-message -p '#W'
```

See the man page for the various ways to specify a target window (search for “target-window” in the *Commands* section).

Answer (score 3):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>      tmux [-28lquvVC] [-c shell-command] [-f file] [-L socket-name] [-S socket-path] [command [flags]]

SKIP

> command [flags]
>   This specifies one of a set of commands used to control 
>   tmux, as described in the following sections.  If no commands are
>                      specified, the new-session command is assumed.

You can find full list of tmux commands (two last arguments) in the manual, but now you interest is 'list-windows'.

```
tmux list-windows
0: zsh [156x40] [layout aebd,156x40,0,0,0] @0
1: mc [156x40] [layout aebe,156x40,0,0,1] @1 (active)
```

As you can see active window marked as '(active)'. This is what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

First list all window names and active status, the active one will end with 1, then extract the name before it

```sh
 tmux lsw -F '#{window_name}#{window_active}'|sed -n 's|^\(.*\)1$|\1|p'
```

Answer (score 0):

The **FORMATS** section in the `tmux` [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#FORMATS) contains a great deal of useful info. To wit:

1. You can use "prebuild" format codes like `#W`
2. There is a list of defined fields that can be printed individually, like `window_name`.
3. There are "condition variables" that take the value 1 when true, and not-1 otherwise, like `window_active`.
4. There are "conditional expressions" that expand to either of two values, depending on their target.

Putting that together, I came up with:

```
$ tmux list-windows -F "#{?window_active,#{window_name},}"
primary

$
```

Where "primary" is the name of my currently-active window (set moments before using `tmux rename-window`) and I have 2 other windows that are not active, and so presented as blank lines.

Considering the shell eats whitespace, you can probably do something like

```
ACTIVE_WINDOW=$(tmux list-windows -F "#{?window_active,#{window_name},}")
```

in a script.

Comment: Also, you should try [kakoune](http://kakoune.org/)! It's modal like vim, but [multi-]selection oriented.